# SharePoint time field value using jQuery

Tags: sharepoint-online, jquery

I am trying to get the time selected from SharePoint list and store it one variable. I have attached an image for reference, Can anyone help me with this?[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to use the jquery, you can do that using vanilla JS `querySelector`

```
var time =   document.querySelector("select[id='Scheduled_x0020_time_0c63521b-1292-45ae-a881-f85e14c83ca7_$DateTimeFieldDateHours'").value + ":" + document.querySelector("select[id='Scheduled_x0020_time_0c63521b-1292-45ae-a881-f85e14c83ca7_$DateTimeFieldDateMinutes'").value 
console.log(time);
```

Explanation,

The `datetime` field has two select controls to show the time value

- `DateTimeFieldDateHours` for **Hours**
- `DateTimeFieldDateMinutes` for **Minutes**

So you are trying to query the selector with the actual ID `id=`, or using contains `id=^` then try to concatenate both values to get the desired value as shown below.

**Output**

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the answer, will try this and let you know.

Answer (score 1):

Mohamed's code is right, if you want to use jQuery code, check the code below.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    var fieldName="Select Scheduled Departure Time";
    var fieldDateHours=$(".ms-standardheader:contains('"+fieldName+"')").closest("tr").find("select[id$='_$DateTimeFieldDateHours']").val();
    var fieldDateMinutes=$(".ms-standardheader:contains('"+fieldName+"')").closest("tr").find("select[id$='_$DateTimeFieldDateMinutes']").val();
    console.log(fieldDateHours+":"+fieldDateMinutes);
})
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, will try this and let you know if its working.

Comment: This function does not get triggered , I want to use this function in the change.function(). Can I use this there?

Comment: It says Uncaught TypeError: $(...).closest is not a function. when I try to run the code which you have mentioned.

Comment: My api request accepts 24 hour format date and I have 12 hour format date like this 9:00 PM and I need it to be as 21:00. How can I do that here in jquery?